# Breaking out of a loop, return to start of loop with correct value of variable

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script

I am sending processes to a server, but I only want a certain number running at a time. Thus I loop which checks how many jobs are running and only submits new one if the current amount of jobs do not exceed some measure. To this end I need to wait if the current queue is full, to submit more jobs.

I am wondering how I would achieve this via something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in `seq 10`; do
    if [ condition1 -le condition2 ]; do
        #>>> Submit jobs
    else
        # SERVER IS FULL
        #
        # Wait 10min and try again, by returning to start of the loop
        # with the current value of $i intact
        sleep 10m 
done
```

If my intuition is correct the above loop will try the next time with `$(($i + 1))` if the server is full at step `$i` - thus leaving some jobs unprocessed.

Any suggestions for how this can be dealt with? I.e. how can I break out of the second clause (`else`) and return to the start of the loop.

Comment: Instead of `if condition do process else wait`, try `while not condition wait ; do process`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple solution is to change your logic slightly:

```
i=1;
while [ "$i" -le 10 ]; do
    if [ condition1 -le condition2 ]; do
        #>>> Submit jobs

        ## Increment the value of $i if a job was submitted
        i=$((i+1))
    else
        # SERVER IS FULL
        #
        # Wait 10min and try again, by returning to start of the loop
        # with the current value of $i intact
        sleep 10m 
done
```

This way, `$i` will only be incremented when a job was submitted. If the server is full, the script will wait 10 minutes and repeat with the same value of `$i`.

Comment: Waiting now :) - could one potentially use `retry` and `until` as well in cases like this?

Comment: @Astrid bash has no `retry` as far as I know but yes, you can do `until [ "$i" = 11 ]` for example.